# select value from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html-select

I want to make this source code, I copy this source code in my notepad and I paste it in one file, include CSS, JavaScript and HTML. The file name is *sel.php*.

I take the source code from http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x5YW3/

I include my CSS with:

```
<style type="text/css">
----this_source_css----
</style>
```

JavaScript with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
----this_source_javascript----
</script>
```

And HTML in:

```
<html>
<body>
----html_source_code----
</body>
</html>
```

But this code does not work in my copy paste, whereas I run in jsfiddle working fine, what might be wrong?

Comment: You need a `head` element and put the CSS and Javascript in there. See eg. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/13-the-html-head-element/ (doesn't matter that it's marked deprecated)

Comment: Are you also including the jQuery library used in the linked jfiddle?

Comment: @Pekka i use `<head>` and doesn't work.
@Boaz jquery ? jquery from where ? in jsfiddle, i'm not see jquery source code.

Comment: @insomniart show your full HTML

Comment: @Pekka i'm sory i paste in field html http://jsfiddle.net/insomniart/yyaV5/

and thanks for your response,

Comment: The JSFiddle is not helpful here, as it will serve a document that already has a head section and other parts of the body. You'll need to show us the naked HTML that isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess - include your javascript-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your code here
});
```

Also make sure you included JQuery source in your file.

However, Your fiddle code is being executed  "onLoad" - check the dropbox below "Choose Framework".

As Pekka pointed out, if you do intend your code to run after "load" instead when your dom is ready, you can use this -

```
$(document).load(function() {
// your code here
});
```

An explanation of the difference between the two events is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683072/jquery-events-load-ready-unload)

Comment: oh.. thanxs, because iam newbie in javascript, @johnbk many thanks for you,

Answer (score 1):

As @Boaz Said:

You haven't included jQuery in your document. Get the latest version from jquery.com and also use this:

```
$( function() {

// paste js code here

});
```