# bootstrap datepicker not working[displaying] on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got Bootstrap datepicker in my form, at first it was working fine but now, after i used jquery .load function to load the form which contained the datepicker element, it wont work/show itself upon first click but when i click outside and click again then gives me this error in console of firebug:

```
TypeError: date is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

var parts = date.split(format.separator),
```

and the datepicker appears....

i have used this javascript to hide the datepicker:

```
$(document).on('click','.datepicker', function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: "yyyy-mm-dd" }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
  });
})
```

Comment: this may be a helpful link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683072/jquery-events-load-ready-unload. Probably it because the DOM may not be ready, at that time of loading

and also try loading the date picker separately in a ready function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your datepicker before they click.  You probably should use a callback on .load:

```
$('#formdiv').load('yourform.php', function() {
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({ format: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

This way the element exists, and you tell it what to do when they click BEFORE they click.

Answer (score 1):

So maybe you need is this.

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/500#issuecomment-34662552

where $('.datepicker') is a selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include it in body onload tag:

```
<body onload="$('#fecha').datepicker();" ...
```

and also call it in your input (with class="datepicker") with onclick event :

```
<input id="fecha" name="fecha" class="default datepicker" onclick="$('#fecha').datepicker();" placeholder="FECHA">
```