# How to run function in function

Tags: javascript

I have this function, it should track ctrk+enter keys and send message. But function don't work. But if i call `HotKeys();` in console, it works. So how to trigger it when script loaded? I new to javascript. Thanks and sry for my english.

```
function HotKeys() {
$('#msgbox').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("go").click();
    }
});
}     
HotKeys();
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the DOM to load before calling `HotKeys()`?

Comment: Have you tried: $( document ).ready(function() {HotKeys();}); ??

Comment: Everything you need to know: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2683072/1816580

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the function on load by using:
    window.onload = HotKeys();

If you want the function to be run anytime the hot keys are pressed, remove the function declaration around it so you just have the function body

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a function, but attach a document ready handler like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#msgbox").keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#go").click();
        }
    });
});
```

This will register your handler when the document is ready. with your code, you indeed had to call `HotKeys` in order to register the handler.

Comment: You're welcome. But, as a reminder, you should tick answers that did work for you as accepted (you can upvote good answers if you wish too). I'm telling you this because I noticed you didn't mark any of your questions as resolved so far. And it gives you +2 rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(function HotKeys() {
    $('#msgbox').keydown(function (e) {
        // when user presses ctrl + enter, click the "go" button
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById("go").click();
        }
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: Post some explanation so that it is easy for the OP to understand