# Javascript not executing on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When my page reloads via a user clicking one of my checkboxes, my JS does not execute.

What happens is that URL variables are appended to the URL (for size, color, price, etc etc., depending on what the user is clicking) and when that happens, the JS is somehow left unexecuted.

What the JS does is create a class to my UL called SizeChicklets. Also, I am only able to use jQuery 1.3.2 due to SaaS platform limitations.

Here is what my boxes look like on a successful page load, before I click any of the boxes:

[image: Before]

And  here is what my boxes look like on an unsuccessful page load, when I click any of the boxes:

[image: unsuccessful page load]

This happens because the class I am appending to my UL is being done via Javascript. Then, that class is being styled. However, I want the JS to execute when the page reloads, so I don't have this problem.

My URL when I first arrive at the Product Refinement page looks like this:

```
.com/s?defaultSearchTextValue=Search&searchKeywords=*&Action=submit
```

Then, upon clicking one of the boxes (Value: 9M), the URL changes to look like this:

```
.com/s?defaultSearchTextValue=Search&searchKeywords=*&Action=submit&field_subjectbin=&field_brandtextbin=&field_price=&field_generic_text_2-bin=&field_generic_text_1-bin=&field_size_name=9M&searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&searchSize=12&searchPage=1&searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var sizeUL = jQuery('.binName').filter(function(){
        return this.innerHTML.trim() == 'Size';
    }).next("ul")
    sizeUL.addClass('SizeChicklets');
    /*Prepend and Append clear div*/
    jQuery('.binName').filter(function(){
        return this.innerHTML.trim() == 'Size';
    }).prepend('<div style="clear: both;">').append('</div>');
    /* AJAX SIZE SELECTOR */
    jQuery("li a", sizeUL).click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('SizeChickletSelected')) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('SizeChickletSelected');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).addClass('SizeChickletSelected');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML (before SizeChicklets is appended to the UL):

```
<ul class="linkList" id="binValue-6">      
    <li class="binValue">
        <input name="binId" value="size_name" type="hidden">
        <input name="binValue" value="0-3 Months" type="hidden">
        <a href=".com/s?field_size_name=0-3+Months&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchBinNameList=subjectbin%2Cbrandtextbin%2Cprice%2Cgeneric_text_2-bin%2Cgeneric_text_1-bin%2Csize_name&amp;searchKeywords=*&amp;searchNodeID=5690131011&amp;searchRank=generic-one-desc-rank&amp;searchSize=12" rel="nofollow"> 
            <input type="checkbox">0-3 Months
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.SizeChicklets {
   /* JUST UL STYLES */
   clear: both;
}

.SizeChicklets:after {
   /* JUST UL STYLES */
   clear: both;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
}

.binName {
    clear:both;
}

.SizeChicklets li {
    /* JUST LI STYLES */
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.SizeChicklets li a input{
    display:none;
}

.SizeChicklets li a {
    /* JUST A STYLES */
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%, #5f5f5f 20%, #3f3f3f 75%, #343434 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#666666), color-stop(20%,#5f5f5f), color-stop(75%,#3f3f3f), color-stop(100%,#343434)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%,#5f5f5f 20%,#3f3f3f 75%,#343434 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%,#5f5f5f 20%,#3f3f3f 75%,#343434 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #666666 0%,#5f5f5f 20%,#3f3f3f 75%,#343434 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #666666 0%,#5f5f5f 20%,#3f3f3f 75%,#343434 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#666666', endColorstr='#343434',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    min-width:33px;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white!important;
}

.SizeChicklets li a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.SizeChicklets li a:hover {
    /* JUST A STYLES */
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #de9b00; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%, #d99505 25%, #c47d0f 95%, #c37c0d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#de9b00), color-stop(25%,#d99505), color-stop(95%,#c47d0f), color-stop(100%,#c37c0d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#de9b00', endColorstr='#c37c0d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
}

.SizeChickletSelected {
    /* JUST A STYLES */
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #de9b00; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%, #d99505 25%, #c47d0f 95%, #c37c0d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#de9b00), color-stop(25%,#d99505), color-stop(95%,#c47d0f), color-stop(100%,#c37c0d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #de9b00 0%,#d99505 25%,#c47d0f 95%,#c37c0d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#de9b00', endColorstr='#c37c0d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you could try changing document.ready to : Sys.Application.add_load(function() {  It needs scriptmanager to work.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683072/jquery-events-load-ready-unload

Comment: @pc-shooter yeah, none of that helps at all. drzounds I have no idea what that is.

Comment: sry to hear that. I'll think about giving a bounty by tommorow or so. BTW I don't think that CSS is part of the problem. You should delete that part. also delete the 'CSS' tag

Comment: Are you sure there is a full page reload when url changes?

What I think is happening is that SaaS platform is handling clicks with Ajax and after that it rebuilds the checkbox list and changes the url using History API. You would have to find a way how to execute your JavaScript code after that Ajax request, but the options depends on how exactly is this implemented.

If it does reload a page, then verify that your JavaScript code is present in the code of that second page and that the UL selector is matching the HTML code.